# Reverse for 'update_cart' not found. 'update_cart' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

I am new in django and i am developing one application in that on click i am trying to add product in cart. To select product i am using `"{%url 'update_cart' product1.slug%}">` in my template, I am including my code here.

This is model

```
models.py
class cart(models.Model):
    product=models.ManyToManyField(products,blank=True)
    total=models.DecimalField(max_digits=100,decimal_places=2,default=0.00)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "cart id: %s" %(self.id)
```

This is views

```
views.py

def cartpage(request):
    c_data=cart.objects.all()[0]
    return render(request,'cart/cart.html',{'c_data':c_data})

def update_cart(request,slug):
    c_data = cart.objects.all()[0]
    try:
        product1=products.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except products.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass
    if not product1 in c_data.product.all():
        c_data.product.add(product1)
    else:
        c_data.product.remove(product1)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```

This is urls

```
urls.py

path('cart/',views.cartpage,name='cart'),
path('cart/<slug:slug>',views.update_cart,name='update_cart')
```

I have created cart model and registered it in admin...its working properly even in my cart.html page is also working,but if i try to add product on click in cart page its giving me error.

please help

Comment: Did you define an `app_name` in your `urls.py`?

Comment: Yes, i have already defined app name in urls..but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

in urls.py of your app:

```
# imports
app_name = your_app_name
urlpatterns = [
    # other urls
    path('cart/',views.cartpage,name='cart'),
    path('cart/<slug:slug>',views.update_cart,name='update_cart'),
]
```

in templates call urls by app namespace:

```
"{% url 'your_app_name:update_cart' product1.slug %}"
```

Refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#id5)

**Update**:
make sure that `product1.slug` is there. If there is not, the url lookup will fail.

```
 "Reverse for 'update_cart' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/cart/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$'] "
```

means that, no arguments were passed to the url named `update_cart`. Here, the argument being `product1.slug`.

`"{% url 'your_app_name:update_cart' product1.slug %}"` seems you have passed. Check if slug is there for `product1` object since `product1.slug` has not been rendered to the template.

Comment: I have already defined app name in urls and tried by changing in template..as "{% url 'cart:update_cart' product1.slug %}"> but still its not working...and error is "Reverse for 'update_cart' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/cart/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
"

Comment: @swap okay. can you check if there is a valid url in your page source after rendering. A url matching the pattern. `cart/<slug>`. the <slug> may not be there after rendering